# How to make sure that certain class can only be accessed by another class but not others?

Tags: vb.net

Say in my vb.net program I already have too many classes and module.

I want to normalize things a bit. So I want to create a new class called FolderStats and I want folderstats to be accessible only by another class folderStatsuser.

I do not want any other class to know that FolderStats even exist

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an assembly and use the [Friend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76453kax.aspx) access modifier so that only classes in the assembly can access your class. Classes that shouldn't access it would need to be in another assembly.

Comment: This is not correct. Friend class is accessible by all classes in the same assembly, not only in the same namespace.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I was meaning 'assembly'. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If *only* FolderStatsUser should have any knowledge of it, then it is an implementation detail of FolderStatsUser. Having a private class might be useful

```
public class FolderStatsUser {
       private class FolderStats {}
}
```

Comment: Converted to vb .net below in another answer.

Answer (score 2):

@Jim - here is the vb.net version...

```
Public Class FolderStatsUser 
    Private Class FolderStats 
    End Class
End Class
```

You can read more about nested classes at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twwxww86(v=vs.71).aspx